# Read Soap Header

Tags: php, soap

I am sending a Soap Requst in php and want to see the complete xml soap request. How do I output the xml  or see the xml in firefox?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php

```
<?php
$client = SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('trace' => 1));
$result = $client->SomeFunction();
echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest() . "\n";
```

There's also `__getLastRequestHeaders()`, `__getLastResponse()`, and `__getLastResponseHeaders()`